# A question on pseudospectra of matrix polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose:

- ${A_j} \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},0<{w_j}\in \mathbb{R} (j = 0,1,2....m)$
- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable.
- ${\rm{q(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{w}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{w_1}\lambda  + {w_0}$
- ${\sigma _{\varepsilon ,w}}(P) = \left\{ {\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| {P{{(\lambda )}^{ - 1}}} \right\| \ge {{(\varepsilon q(\left| \lambda  \right|))}^{ - 1}}} \right\}$, where $\left\| . \right\|$ is any subordinate matrix norm.

Why does boundary of ${\sigma _{\varepsilon ,w}}(P)$ can be written in the form $S = \left\{ {\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| {P{{(\lambda )}^{ - 1}}} \right\| = {{(\varepsilon q(\left| \lambda  \right|))}^{ - 1}}} \right\}$.